# Check who opened my cd tray

Tags: windows, event-log

There is this old "prank" where people can open your cd tray by running:

```
compmgmt.msc /computer:\\computername
```

Then go to repositories > disk management > CD Rom > Eject

Someone in my workplace has been opening someone else's tray and they think it's me. And, it was not.

Is there a place on their computer where you can see who connected to your computer via this tool? Or in the prankster's computer?

Comment: One suggestion : Discover who it was, through packet sniffing on the victim's PC, enabling and reviewing WMI logs on the victim's PC, or some other investigation.  Another suggestion : Disable remote computer management on the victim's PC.  You can then test from your PC intentionally.  There may be another reason why the tray is opening, for instance, a physical issue with the drive or some other non-prank cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the Windows Event Viewer, inside the Security log.

You will find "Audit Success" events (ID: 4624); Look through the ones titled "Logon" in the Task Category column, to determine who's connecting at the time(s) in question.

The event entry should show you both the user name logging in, and the IP they are connecting from.  The ones with "Logon Type: 3" means it was a network connection, which is the type of login that Compmgmt.msc from a remote computer wwould use.

Keep in mind that not every "Logon type: 3" is compmgmt.msc; it could be any type of network connection that required logon.  hence why you'll want to use the time(s) of occurrence to narrow it down.

Comment: Well who was it?  And did they get fired? :)

Comment: No but they got mad at him hahaha. He saw me teaching it to the other guy the other day. And now he was using my trick against me